# Processing Nikon D5300 Raw images in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, gimp, image-processing, darktable

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I have installed both UFRaw and DarkTable.
but I have problems processing Nikon D5300 raw files (.nef).

Every raw image I open in either application has a purple tint. I think
the problem is with the decoder. I searched for Nikon d5300 color profile
file (.icc) to import but could not find anything.

Has anyone experienced this problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Related: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/58095/why-does-darktable-show-d5300-raw-nef-in-pink-in-darkroom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://launchpad.net/~dhor/+archive/ubuntu/myway  update DCRAW with this PPA and the latest DCRAW supports D5300.

Comment: Very good PPA. I installed GTKRawGallery from it. Works vergy good.